# Opening CSV in Excel not displaying Datetime2 correctly

Tags: excel, azure, csv, azure-data-factory

I am building an ETL solution in Azure Data Factory that calls a stored proc and populates a CSV

The date columns are defined as datetime2 in the source and is being mapped to datetime in the CSV:

[image]

When I open the CSV in Excel, the dates are displayed as `00:00.0` with the formula bar showing `09/04/2019  00:00:00`:

```
Risk_Inception_Date Risk_Expiry_Date
00:00.0 00:00.0
00:00.0 00:00.0
00:00.0 00:00.0
00:00.0 00:00.0
00:00.0 00:00.0
00:00.0 00:00.0
00:00.0 00:00.0
00:00.0 00:00.0
```

If I save the CSV in Excel and open it in Notepad++ the dates change to `00:00.0`

[image]

This is causing me a massive headache and can't find a way around it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Brian

EDIT1: As per Marc's suggestion, map all the datetime2 source fields to plain text in the ADF control flows?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to map it to just plain text? I've had a lot of problems with excel and date/time fields in the past so now I just use plain text.

Comment: So you would map all the datetime2 source fields as plain text in the CSV? Have added a EDIT1 with screenshot

Comment: Please edit your question to contain formatted text, vs images of text (at a minimum, for the input and output data). This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important.

Comment: Hi @DavidMakogon, I've added formatted text now. Hope it looks better

Comment: @Brian - I don't see it. Maybe you didn't save your edits? I'm talking about your CSV data. Like... the block of data that comes out of Excel.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Apologies, I've updated it again

Comment: @Brian - I don't think you understand what I'm saying. I mean, like... actual text, with formatting characters inside your question. Text that can be selected/copied. Not uploaded jpg/png of text. Take a look at the text-formatting options in the editor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237212/discussion-between-brian-and-david-makogon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the source **Date** to the required format under Mapping in `Type Conversion Settings`.

You can add your custom date format for conversion in **dateTimeFormat** or **dateTimeOffsetFormat** for example, **MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff**

[image]

**Output before conversion:**

[image]

**Output after adding type conversion in ADF mapping:**

[image]

Comment: This looks like the best solution. I've not implemented this yet but this looks to be exactly what I need. Many thanks!